# What does this fix for non-responsive mouse and keyboard do?

Tags: mouse, display, performance

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 and found that after about 20 minutes of work that my mouse and keyboard became very unresponsive. So I found the following fix (logging in as root - careful!!!):

```
sudo -i
```

To test if this is the problem:

```
echo N> /sys/module/drm_kms_helper/parameters/poll
```

To make the fix permanent:

```
echo "options drm_kms_helper poll=N">/etc/modprobe.d/local.conf
```

It appears that the fix does work, but what does this do? Am I breaking something else in doing this?

I don't like changing default settings without knowing what it's doing, so I just want to find out what this does, and if it may have any adverse side-effects.

Comment: Cool, question is updated to make my intentions clearer